# Get value of column in AWS Glue Custom Transform

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm working on ETL in AWS Glue. I need to decode text from table which is in base64 - I'm doing that in Custom Transform in Python3.

My code is below:

```
def MyTransform (glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
import base64
    
newdf = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()

data = newdf["email"]

data_to_decrypt = base64.b64decode(data)
```

I've got error like that:

```
TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'Column'
```

How to get plan string from the Column object?

Comment: Can you `print(data)` and update the question with the outcome?

Comment: @Marcin sadly, print doesn't work in AWS Glue. When I try to fill in another column with 'data', it's showing the same value as in email. Obviously it's a Column object though and I don't know how to extract simple string from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong and it was completely different thing than I thought.

Column object from newdf["email"] consists all rows for this single column, so it's not possible to just fetch one value from that.

What I ended up doing is iterating through whole rows and mapping them to new value like that:

```
def map_row(row):
    id = row.id
    client_key = row.client_key
    email = decrypt_jasypt_string(row.email.strip())
    phone = decrypt_jasypt_string(row.phone.strip())
    created_on = row.created_on
    return (id, email, phone, created_on, client_key)

df = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()

rdd2=df.rdd.map(lambda row: map_row(row))
df2=rdd2.toDF(["id","email","phone", "created_on", "client_key"])

dyf_filtered = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df2, glueContext, "does it matter?")
```